# Can multiple process pull off the same record from an Oracle FIFO queue?

Tags: oracle

My understanding of Oracle AQ (Advanced Queuing) is that no two (or more) processes can pull off (drain/consume) the same record of an Oracle FIFO queue.  Is this correct or is some code needed to prevent this from occurring?